# How to implement lazy ShareLink in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, does anyone know how we can implement a lazy version of [`ShareLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sharelink) for SwiftUI?

Imagine if the item you're sharing involves some significant processing. For instance, you're generating a report that requires processing of lots of data. I wouldn't want that processing to occur just to create a button to generate the report; instead, I'd want to supply a closure that would be called to generate the report only when the user taps on the button.

Running this example code confirms to me that the normal API isn't doing what I'd like (when the app launches, I see the message "generateReport has been called", even before I tap the ShareLink):

```swift
struct ShareTest: View {
    func generateReport() -> String {
        print ("generateReport has been called")
        return "This is an expensive report"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ShareLink(item: generateReport())
    }
}
```

Is there some API I've missed that lets me achieve lazy computing of the report? If there is no API that supports it directly, is there a creative way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the generated report is itself [`Transferable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreTransferable/Transferable) (e.g. `String`), you can make your own `Transferable` type with a [`ProxyRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretransferable/proxyrepresentation):

```
struct Report: Transferable {
    
    // you can add properties here that can be used for generating the report

    func generateReport() -> String {
        print("Generating...")
        // do some work...
        return "A generated report"
    }
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        ProxyRepresentation { report in
            report.generateReport()
        }
    }
}
```

```
ShareLink(
    item: Report(/* pass information needed here*/), 
    preview: .init("Some Report")
)
```

"Generating..." will only be printed when the user chooses a share action.

If the report is not `Transferable`, you can convert it into `Data`, and use a [`DataRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretransferable/datarepresentation) instead.

Comment: Ah, excellent. This solves the problem, exactly as I'd hoped. Thank you! I'll have to dig into the details of Transferable and ProxyRepresentation, but this sounds like a great direction to head in.

Comment: This approach is deprecated in iOS 17: 'init(exporting:)' was deprecated in iOS 17.0: A synchronous exporter should be used instead.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Oh you're right! Xcode's documentation window doesn't say this (probably because I'm still using 15.0), but the online documentation does say it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIActivityViewController, this way the `generateReport()` function will be run only whenever a user clicks it.

```
struct ShareTest: View {
    
    private func generateReport(url: URL) {
        
        let finalString = """
                Checkout this website at
                \(url.absoluteString)
                """
        
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [finalString], applicationActivities: nil)
        
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        print ("generateReport has been called")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button {
                if let url = URL(string: "www.google.com") {
                    generateReport(url: url)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("lol")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. That works! Thanks. It would be even better if it stayed more within the bounds of SwiftUI. But it's still great to know about this option!